# Ubuntu 12.04 window management bug with Grid/Put and multiple displays

Tags: unity, compiz, shortcut-keys, window-manager, window

In Ubuntu CompizConfig Settings Manager, there are two very useful window management plugins.

"Grid" does essentially the same thing (and then some) that Windows Aero "snap" does.  Via mouse actions and keyboard shortcuts you can snap the active window to various preset locations (left half of screen, upper right quarant, etc).  However, these keyboard shortcuts only work on the active display (i.e. you can't move the window out of the current display using any of these).

"Put" allows you to use a keyboard shortcut to move the active window from the current display to another one.  It works great, UNLESS you've previously used the grid plugin to snap the window into place.  In this case, the window will move to the new display as desired, but then about 1 second later it will bounce back.  To be clear: the window will only move across screens via the "put" keyboard shortcut, if that window was NOT previously snapped to a preset "grid" location.

Has anybody else experienced this?  Any ideas for a solution?

Comment: What window are you moving? what is the error? more specifically please?

Comment: Any window.  File browser, terminal, web browser, etc.  I think I was very specific about the error, but to be clear: the expected output of the PUT command is that the window moves from one display to the next and stays there.  The output described in my scenario is that the window moves to the next display but does not stay... it bounces back 1 second later.

Comment: I have the same issue (14.04), but only if I maximized to a *quadrant* with Grid. If I `Left Maximize` or `Right Maximize` with Grid, Put manages to `Put To Next Output`. So a workaround when your window is quadrant maximized is to first maximize to half screen, put to next output, then maximize back to your quadrant. It's a pain.

Answer (score 0):

well, i didnt understand what you meant by window, but i believe the case is you want to bring an open file to a new window on your selectory? well i have had this experience in which i discovered add the window selector to your taskbar and then drag your file to the bar, it will open the four windows and then allow you to place the file